# Why doesn't the pagination work for a comment type, but it works for the other one?

Tags: 8, comments

I have a custom content type with multiple comment types.

1. Query comments
2. Discussion comments

I set the pagination limit for the both the comments as 10. The node detail page, when the number of comments exceeds 10, shows the pagination. For the discussion comments, only 10 comments are shown, even if they are more; no pagination is shown.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than one listing on a page, the pager ID for each needs to be different. This applies to views, but also comment lists.

The way to change this is under your content type's display settings (`admin/structure/types/manage/MYTYPE/display`). For the comment fields, click on the gear icon and you should see this configuration option:

[image]

So long as each comment type uses a different ID, the pagers should work independently of each other.